# How do I rearrange elements in a matrix, moving them in a certain direction based on their value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I have created a CodePen here: https://codepen.io/rickgove/pen/jOMxZYj?editors=0010

I have a matrix in JavaScript:

```js
let m = [
  ["0",      "0",      "S",       "S",       "0",   "0"],
  ["0",      "S", "D^left", "D^right",       "S",   "0"],
  ["S", "D^left", "Dvleft", "Dvright", "D^right",   "S"],
  ["S", "Dvleft",   "D<up",    "D>up", "Dvright",   "S"],
  ["0",      "S", "D<down",  "D>down",       "S",   "0"],
  ["0",      "0",      "S",       "S",       "0",   "0"]
];
```

I want to rearrange the matrix so that elements with a direction word will move in that direction. Any spot where an item has been moved and no item has moved to take it's place should be `"S"`

My desired result is

```
 m = [
  [     "0",      "0",      "S",      "S",       "0",       "0"],
  [     "0", "D^left",      "S",      "S", "D^right",       "0"],
  ["D^left", "Dvleft",   "D<up",   "D>up", "Dvright", "D^right"],
  ["Dvleft",      "S",      "S",      "S",       "S", "Dvright"],
  [     "0",      "S",      "S",      "S",       "S",       "0"],
  [     "0",      "0", "D<down", "D>down",       "0",       "0"]
];
```

This is one of the **many** ways I have tried. Nothing has been successful and I'm stuck.

```js
m.forEach((row, rowInd) => {
  row.forEach((item, itemInd) => {
    if (m[rowInd + 1] && item.includes("down")) {
      m[rowInd + 1][itemInd] = item;
      m[rowInd][itemInd] = "S";
    }
    if (m[rowInd][itemInd - 1] && item.includes("left")) {
      m[rowInd][itemInd - 1] = item;
      m[rowInd][itemInd] = "S";
    }
    if (m[rowInd][itemInd + 1] && item.includes("right")) {
      m[rowInd][itemInd + 1] = item;
      m[rowInd][itemInd] = "S";
    }
    if (m[rowInd - 1] && item.includes("up")) {
      m[rowInd - 1][itemInd] = item;
      m[rowInd][itemInd] = "S";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What happens if an item is at the edge and needs to be moved? For example `["D^left", "0"]`

Comment: It doesn't move @VLAZ

Comment: and what happens if an item wants to move to a box which contains a `0`?

Comment: There is no run button in your codepen. Is there something missing? Stackoverflow also has a codepen-like feature.

Comment: @ubaidshaikh It may not move there either. a 0 is essentially a non-existent tile

Comment: @KonradHöffner It's all on the console.log

Comment: A classic bug for this kind of code is that when you move an element to the right, and move your position also to the right, you will encounter the element again and move it to the right, etc. You can avoid it via complicated magic, or just work with two arrays, one you read and one you write.

Answer (score 0):

You need to still test for edge cases but the most important point is to operate on a deep clone of the array, or you will move elements multiple times, as noted by @tevemadar.

```
let m = [
  ["0", "0", "S", "S", "0", "0"],
  ["0", "S", "D^left", "D^right", "S", "0"],
  ["S", "D^left", "Dvleft", "Dvright", "D^right", "S"],
  ["S", "Dvleft", "D<up", "D>up", "Dvright", "S"],
  ["0", "S", "D<down", "D>down", "S", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "S", "S", "0", "0"]
];

let old = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m)); // hacky way to obtain deep clone

old.forEach((row, rowInd) => {
  row.forEach((item, itemInd) => {
    if (old[rowInd + 1] && item.includes("down")) {
      m[rowInd + 1][itemInd] = item;
      m[rowInd][itemInd] = "S";
    }
    if (old[rowInd][itemInd - 1] && item.includes("left")) {
      m[rowInd][itemInd - 1] = item;
      m[rowInd][itemInd] = "S";
    }
    if (old[rowInd][itemInd + 1] && item.includes("right")) {
      m[rowInd][itemInd + 1] = item;
      m[rowInd][itemInd] = "S";
    }
    if (old[rowInd - 1] && item.includes("up")) {
      m[rowInd - 1][itemInd] = item;
      m[rowInd][itemInd] = "S";
    }
  });
});

console.log(old);
console.log(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the moving items and check if the moving item collides with another item for moving.

```js
const
    move = ([offsetI, offsetJ]) => ([i, j]) => {
        m[i + offsetI][j + offsetJ] = m[i][j];
        m[i][j] = EMPTY;
    },
    m = [
        ["0", "0", "S", "S", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "S", "D^left", "D^right", "S", "0"],
        ["S", "D^left", "Dvleft", "Dvright", "D^right", "S"],
        ["S", "Dvleft", "D<up", "D>up", "Dvright", "S"],
        ["0", "S", "D<down", "D>down", "S", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "S", "S", "0", "0"]
    ],
    EMPTY = 'S',
    directions = { up: [-1, 0], down: [1, 0], left: [0, -1], right: [0, 1] },
    movingItems = [];


for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
        const type = m[i][j].match(/up|down|left|right/)?.[0];
        if (!type) continue;
        movingItems.push([type, i, j]);
    }
}

while (movingItems.length) {
    let k = 0;
    while (k < movingItems.length) {
        const
            [offsetI, offsetJ] = directions[movingItems[k][0]];
            i = movingItems[k][1],
            j = movingItems[k][2];
        if (/up|down|left|right/.test(m[i + offsetI][j + offsetJ])) {
            k++;
            continue;
        }
        m[i + offsetI][j + offsetJ] = m[i][j];
        m[i][j] = EMPTY;
        movingItems.splice(k, 1);
    }
}

m.forEach(a => console.log(...a.map(v => v.padStart(8))));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, among possible issues is you need to handle scenarios where your moving elements are moving into a space occupied by another moving element.

After testing your code, it looks like on row 3, the element on index 3 moves into index 4, which is occupied by a piece that would move right. Then, when the forEach loop moves onto the next index, it moves right again.

Under the current logic, any right moving piece would endlessly move right as the for loop is navigated.

Consider instead of updating the board as you go, adding the updated tiles to a new matrix, then at the end, replacing your m matrix with the new matrix.